# Get the total of items after using appendTo

Tags: jquery, appendto

My HTML looks like this :

```
<ul class="slideShow">
    <li><img src="img/slides/white_album.jpg" width="300" height="250" alt="White album"></li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, i'm preloading and injecting more `<li>` elements into the `ul`, like so:

```
var target = $(".slideShow");
var banners = [];
function set_preload_banners() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "include/get_banners.php",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
            if ( !(jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) ) {
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    banners[i] = new Image();
                    banners[i].src = 'img/slides/' + item[2];
                    banners[i].onload = function() {
                        var attr = $("<li></li>").appendTo(target);

                        $(this).width(this.width).height(this.height).attr("alt", "").appendTo(attr);
                    }
                });
            }

            SlideShow();

        }).fail(function(data) {
        }).always(function(data) {
        });
}
```

So far so good.
Here's my problem. When calling the function `SlideShow`, to get the number of slides (to use later in a loop), i always get 1. I'm injecting 12 `<li>` items but i always get 1.

```
function SlideShow() {
        var slides = $(".slideShow>li");
        var totalSlides = slides.length;

        alert(totalSlides);
}
```

How do i get the right total after injecting items in a list?

Comment: have you tried using a setTimeout when you call the SlideShow() function? It's possible that at the time you call that the elements are not yet on the page.

Comment: @EricBellDesigns: Good point. Tried using setTimeout(SlideShow, 5000); and, indeed, i do get the correct total. Im guessing there is no solution other then use a timeout.

Comment: @Marco Try putting `SlideShow();` into the `.always` block.

Comment: @Marco I'm sure you could play around with reducing the setTimeout time so the delay is barely noticeable if at all.